# destructor when stopping idhttp.get ( indy, delphi)

Tags: delphi, destructor, terminate, disconnect, idhttp

My application can download one picture from every url in memo1.
It uses idhttp.get and has a skipbutton. After skip it downloads the next picture.

**Q1: Do you have code to put into the destructor and what is the  code for " terminate" and "waitfor"?**
I found this on another website:

```
destructor thread.destroy;
begin
try
Terminate;
If HTTP.Connected then HTTP.Disconnect;
finally
WaitFor;
FreeAndNil(HTTP);
end;
inherited;
end;
```

**Q2: How do I call the destructor and make it work?**

**Q3: Do you have hints (especially security concerns) and additional lines of  code?**

the code of my application:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

type
       thread = class
  public
      Constructor Create; overload;
      Destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    startbutton: TButton;
    skipbutton: TButton;

    procedure startbuttonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure skipbuttonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdHTTP1Work(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
      const AWorkCount: Integer);

         end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
     http: tidhttp;
     s: boolean;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

            constructor thread.Create;
begin
      HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      inherited ;
end;

           destructor thread.destroy;
begin
try

If HTTP.Connected then HTTP.Disconnect;
finally
FreeAndNil(HTTP);
end;
inherited;
end;


procedure TForm1.startbuttonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
i: integer;
  fs : TFileStream ;
begin
for i:= 0 to memo1.lines.count-1 do begin
s:= false;
   fs := TFileStream.Create(inttostr(i)+'abc.jpg', fmCreate);
   http:= idhttp1;
   try
   try
HTTP.Get(memo1.lines[i],fs);
memo2.Lines.add(memo1.Lines[i]);
except
on E: Exception do
begin
memo3.lines.add(' ha ha ha not working   '+syserrormessage(getlasterror));
end;
end;
finally
fs.free;
end;
end;

  end;

procedure TForm1.skipbuttonClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
s:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Work(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  const AWorkCount: Integer);
begin
application.ProcessMessages;

     if s = true then
http.Disconnect;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Why do you have a class named `thread` that isn't a `TThread`? It's a generic `TObject` descendant that basically does nothing except create the *global* instance  of `TIdHTTP`. You also never assign the `IdHttp1.OnWork` event to anything, so `TForm1.IdHTTP1Work` will never be called, so it can't disconnect.

Comment: @KenWhite: I suspect he dropped a IdHttp on his form and implemented the event via the designer. The naming of the "thread" class is really confusing indeed :)

Comment: the application is working like a charm with the code i pasted here. Just the destructor doesn't work.

Comment: Are you thinking you are really using threads in your code??

Comment: I can't see where your class `thread` is used in your example. Please show a test case where your destructor fails.

Comment: @ whosrdaddy: Thanks to your fast answer i know that i don't use threads. But the amazing thing is that the code works. Before i simply disconnected idhttp1 and it raised exceptions and the next picture didn't download.  Do you have code for me to use threads?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Except he's clearly creating a different one than the one dropped on the form in the `thread` class. (The form has `IdHTTP1`, but there's an `http` declared and created in the code, which is then just discarded when the `IdHTTP1` is assigned to it in `startButtonClick`.) This code really is something of a mess, I think.

Comment: @KenWhite: that's why I posted a cleaner version :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy - probably a good idea to also use the Delphi code formatter before pasting.

Answer (score 6):

Since your are using `IdHttp` from the GUI (= main thread) and `Indy` is blocking, you have two options: a) use `IdAntifreeze` in combination with messages (just drop the component on the form), b) use threads.

**Do NOT** use `Application.Processmessages` as it will lead to strange side effects.

now to answer your questions:

**Q1**: the code you found on the internet implemented solution b) so this is not applicable for your current code

**Q2**: same as Q1

**Q3** : here is a version that correctly implements solution a)

This code is still not 100% perfect as it does not implement logic for disabling/enabling the starttransfer and skiptransfer buttons (I leave that as an exercise for you :) ).

```
unit Unit16;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

const
  WM_TRANSFER = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Btn_start: TButton;
    Btn_skip: TButton;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    procedure IdHTTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
    procedure Btn_startClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Btn_skipClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Transferring : Boolean;
    UrlIndex : Integer;
    procedure NextTransfer(var msg : TMessage); message WM_TRANSFER;
    procedure StartTransfer;
    procedure DoTransfer;
    procedure SkipTransfer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.NextTransfer(var msg: TMessage);
begin
 DoTransfer;
end;

procedure TForm1.SkipTransfer;
begin
 Transferring := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartTransfer;
begin
 UrlIndex := 0;
 DoTransfer;
end;

procedure TForm1.DoTransfer;

var
  Url : String;
  Stream : TStringStream;

begin
 if UrlIndex < Memo1.Lines.Count then
  begin
   Url := Memo1.Lines[UrlIndex];
   Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('getting data from URL: %s', [Url]));
   Inc(UrlIndex);
   Transferring := True;
   try
    Stream := TStringStream.Create;
    try
     IdHttp1.Get(Url, Stream);
     Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('Data: "%s"',[Stream.DataString]));
    finally
     Stream.Free;
    end;
   except
    on E: Exception do
     begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('error during transfer: %s', [E.Message]));
     end;
   end;
   Transferring := False;
   PostMessage(Handle, WM_TRANSFER, 0, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Btn_startClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Memo2.Lines.Add('starting transfer');
 StartTransfer;
end;

procedure TForm1.Btn_skipClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Memo2.Lines.Add('skipping current transfer');
 SkipTransfer;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add('work event');
 if not Transferring and (AWorkMode = wmRead) then
 try
  Memo2.Lines.Add('disconnecting peer');
  IdHttp1.Disconnect;
 except
 end;
end;

end.
```

DFM file:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 290
  ClientWidth = 707
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 92
    Top = 12
    Width = 213
    Height = 257
    Lines.Strings = (
      'http://stackoverflow.com'
      'http://www.google.com'
      'http://www.hardocp.com'
      '')
    TabOrder = 0
    WordWrap = False
  end
  object Btn_start: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 128
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Btn_start'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Btn_startClick
  end
  object Btn_skip: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 159
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Btn_skip'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = Btn_skipClick
  end
  object Memo2: TMemo
    Left = 320
    Top = 12
    Width = 373
    Height = 257
    TabOrder = 3
    WordWrap = False
  end
  object IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP
    OnWork = IdHTTP1Work
    AllowCookies = True
    ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication = False
    ProxyParams.ProxyPort = 0
    Request.ContentLength = -1
    Request.ContentRangeEnd = -1
    Request.ContentRangeStart = -1
    Request.ContentRangeInstanceLength = -1
    Request.Accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    Request.BasicAuthentication = False
    Request.UserAgent = 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)'
    Request.Ranges.Units = 'bytes'
    Request.Ranges = <>
    HTTPOptions = [hoForceEncodeParams]
    Left = 24
    Top = 16
  end
  object IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze
    Left = 16
    Top = 72
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. Much cleaner, and `TIdAntiFreeze` was specifically designed to keep the GUI responsive without calling `Application.ProcessMessage` (ugh; I felt a little sick just typing it <g>).

Comment: @whosrdaddy: THANK YOU for your code. I love the idea of option a. 
g2g now I will thoroughly test your code later.